# Maintaining external constraints in table referencing two tables with common reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables in an MSSQL 2012 database and I cant find out if I need to change the design or stick with the constraint I made which I think is a bit cumbersome although it works. Consider the following toy-example:

Consider a library that loans out books and magazines and wants to keep track of the loans. The catch is that magazines and loans have different states and so I end up with these tables:

- MediaType (ID, Name) eg. {"Book", "Magazine"}
- Media (ID, Name, MediaType) eg. {("Gone with the wind", 1), (Time, 2)}
- MediaState (ID, State, MediaType) eg. {("Loaned", 1), ("Reserved", 1), ("Available", 2), ("Stockout", 2)}
- Log (ID, Time, Media, MediaState)

How do I ensure that a log can't be made of a book with the status stockout?

My current solution is to make a check-constraint on Logs calling the function checkStates() that checks if the count of the following is larger than 0:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM Logs l INNER JOIN Media m ON l.Media = m.ID INNER JOIN MediaState ms ON ms.ID = m.MediaState WHERE m.MediaType != ms.MediaType
```

Comment: Where is the table to hold the quantity of each Unit?

Comment: Its a Toy example so no quantities are needed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to have a table to hold the quantity of each Unit (media, mediatype). Then Use a stored procedure to Issue Units

A stored procedure which checks if

```
currentStock - Loaned - Reserved - [Ordered Units] >= 0
```

If above is true then it inserts an entry into Log table. Else it returns a User friendly message saying `Out of stock`... bla bla..

Also add a `BIT` column into your Log table something called `Returned` which sets it to `0` by default and when Item is returned set it to `1.

Comment: Sorry my example was maybe not the best. The problem is that the enum state has to fit the type of the media. No quantities, just valid states

Comment: Your `"Toy Example"` is too toyish to give you a realistic solution. Update your question with more realistic data maybe then someone can help you, cheers

Comment: I made a relational diagram to make it clearer: [link](http://s30.postimg.org/8im1rkzyp/download.png). The example was the best I could do because the real example is really complicated.